# Android will crash depending on layout positioning

Tags: android, android-custom-view, pagerslidingtabstrip

Here's the layout that works :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/mainlayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <com.astuetz.viewpager.extensions.PagerSlidingTabStrip
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dip" >
    </com.astuetz.viewpager.extensions.PagerSlidingTabStrip>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        tools:context=".MainActivity" >
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

</LinearLayout>
```

and here my Activity OnCreate method:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

    adapter = new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    pager.setAdapter(adapter);

    tabs = (PagerSlidingTabStrip) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabs.setViewPager(pager);
    tabs.setDividerColor(Color.BLUE);
    tabs.setBackgroundColor(Color.DKGRAY);
    tabs.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    tabs.setIndicatorColor(Color.GREEN);

}
```

If in the layout I inverse the PagerSlidingTabStrip and the ViewPager, the project will crash at startup, while in the first implementation, it will work fine.

Here's the error :

```
05-19 16:50:11.636: E/AndroidRuntime(305): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-19 16:50:11.636: E/AndroidRuntime(305): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.hsware.peeem/com.hsware.peeem.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
05-19 16:50:11.636: E/AndroidRuntime(305):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
05-19 16:50:11.636: E/AndroidRuntime(305):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
05-19 16:50:11.636: E/AndroidRuntime(305):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
05-19 16:50:11.636: E/AndroidRuntime(305):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
05-19 16:50:11.636: E/AndroidRuntime(305):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-19 16:50:11.636: E/AndroidRuntime(305):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-19 16:50:11.636: E/AndroidRuntime(305):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
05-19 16:50:11.636: E/AndroidRuntime(305):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-19 16:50:11.636: E/AndroidRuntime(305):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
05-19 16:50:11.636: E/AndroidRuntime(305):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
05-19 16:50:11.636: E/AndroidRuntime(305):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
05-19 16:50:11.636: E/AndroidRuntime(305):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-19 16:50:11.636: E/AndroidRuntime(305): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
05-19 16:50:11.636: E/AndroidRuntime(305):  at com.hsware.peeem.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:41)
05-19 16:50:11.636: E/AndroidRuntime(305):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
05-19 16:50:11.636: E/AndroidRuntime(305):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
```

It appears that it can't retrieve de R.id.pager, I'm not sure.

Comment: check the pager import in your Activity

Comment: have you tried cleaning->rebuilding your project after flipping their positions? Stupid, I know, but I've noticed small positioning changes not get picked up by the compiler...

Comment: @Sam_D : Apparently that was that ! Create the answer I'll accept it...

Comment: @TheSquad glad it worked out for you - see my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've noticed that when making small ordering changes, the compiler will not pick it up. A ClassCastException is occurring because findViewById is actually returning the wrong view given R.id.pager, or more accurately - R.id.pager is not referring to the correct view.

The way to fix this is to just clean and re-build your project.

Answer (score 2):

You aren't showing your includes.  There are two definitions for ViewPager, one in android.support.v4.view.ViewPager and one in android.view.ViewPager.  I'll bet that you have included the wrong one in your code.

Comment: it is the support.v4 that I'm using. +1 for showing confusion on Android SDK